# C# variable assignment

Tags: c#, arrays

Can someone show me a simple way to assign variables.
I have many variables and not really know how to do, whether it be possible to use a loop?`

```
public void SwappingPlaces1() 
        {          
            Section_1[0] = Receiver_1[0];
            Section_1[1] = Receiver_2[0];
            Section_1[2] = Receiver_3[0];
            Section_1[3] = Receiver_4[0];
            Section_1[4] = Receiver_5[0];
            Section_1[5] = Receiver_6[0];
            Section_1[6] = Receiver_7[0];
            Section_1[7] = Receiver_8[0];
            Section_1[8] = Receiver_9[0];
            Section_1[9] = Receiver_10[0];
            Section_1[10] = Receiver_11[0];
            Section_1[11] = Receiver_12[0];
            Section_1[12] = Receiver_13[0];
            Section_1[13] = Receiver_14[0];
            Section_1[14] = Receiver_15[0];
            Section_1[15] = Receiver_16[0];
            Section_1[16] = Receiver_17[0];
            Section_1[17] = Receiver_18[0];
            Section_1[18] = Receiver_19[0];
            Section_1[19] = Receiver_20[0];
            Section_1[n]  = Receiver_n[0];             
            ...
}
```

Comment: Use a for loop.

Comment: Strange code, why you have so many different `Receiver[]` when they are arrays anyway?

Comment: Embrace OO.  You should be creating classes to clean up the mess.

Comment: what you want to do with this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use reflection to get the names of the properties/fields by their name. Assuming `Reciever_n` is a property:

```
var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    var p = properties.Single(x => x.Name == "Receiver_" + i);
    var value = p.GetValue(this, new object[] { 0 });
}
```

First you get all the properties defined on the type. Now you loop your list and get that single property with the name `Receiver_` plus the current index.

Finally you invoke that property on the instance and provide the index of the indexed property (which is equal to zero here).

EDIT: However having so many properties with equal name and type seems a design-flaw, you should consider your actual design.

Thus a better appraoch might be to have just one single two-dimensional array `Receiver`.

Comment: I don't know why experienced developers always suggest reflection to newbies. Reflection often indicates a lack in design. Why he has many different `Receiver[]` at all but uses only the first index. I guess one array is sufficient. Or maybe a `Dictionary<int, Receiver>` or something like that. But reflection is the wrong way.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Fair point. Reflection does not neccessarily mean a bad design, however in this case this conclusion might apply.

Answer (score 0):

You could add reference variables to an array and iterate over them. *This is mostly usefull, clearing gui controls, like textboxes/labels etc.*

```
var variables = new[] { Receiver_1, Receiver_2, Receiver_3, Receiver_4, 
                        Receiver_5, Receiver_6 };

for(int i=0; i<Section_1.Length;i++)
    Section_1[i] = variables[i][0];
```

But an index out of bounds is easely created

---

You could also use reflection.